# How to make wall tiles overlap floor tiles a bit in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, tilemap

Currently my tiles are very strictly placed, there are wall tiles, and floor tiles, and they don't overlap at all.

What I want to achieve is to have **my walls overlap my floors a bit**.

So their **inner edges** doesn't have to be a **stright line, but a free shape**, with **"transparent holes"** which **show the floor below**. Resulting in a much better feeling.

[image]

My current approach is to have **multiple layers**. One for the floor and wall (single) tiles), and one above this, which will have the overlapping, decorative parts of the walls.

But this methods **feels slow and clunky**:

For **one wall tile** I have to **place 9 tiles/tileparts** to make it look nice. (the tile itself plus the neighbours).

**It would be better to place just one tile which got overlapping parts**

Comment: Have you considered layering multiple tilemaps on a single grid, so your wall tiles can draw over your floor?

Comment: @DMGregory that's my current approach, but I was wondering whether there is a better approach

Comment: What specific drawback do you experience with your current approach, that you'd like help overcoming? ie. What would make an alternative "better" for your needs?

Comment: For one a wall tile I have to place 9 tiles/tileparts to make it look nice. (the tile itself plus the neighbours). It would be better to place just one tile which got overlapping parts.

Comment: Excellent. Please add that detail to your question — it will help focus answers toward solving that specific issue.

Comment: You can do this with partially transparent tiles like he is doing with the rock tile in that demonstration:
https://youtu.be/fSOYkRU4N9w?t=200

Answer (score 1):

Use a set of tiles that are specific for the place where the walls meet.
[image]
This is an example with 8 tiles. You can make more if you need.
[image]
In this example you see tiles for dirt and grass and areas where the grass and the dirt meet. This image was taken from the Constract 2 Manual.

Comment: Yeah, this is my current approach, but I was wondering whether there is a better approach or not.

Comment: Better is opinion based. :) There are many other things you can do to basically simply draw a randomized curvy line on the screen like using a mesh with some wavy noise but I think you should focus 100% on the gameplay and keep things stupidly simple. No offense to you. It is just as an indie you don't have a lot of resources so minute problems like this don't deserve your time.